# What is fair between 10 owners of an estate?

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, rent, law, estate-settlement

My father passed away in 2014, and my mother in 2012. They left a will 30 years old. They had my 2 sisters as executors.

We were never told anything and they had me and my sister pay rent. I paid for 1 1/2 years and my sister still lived there until they removed her without prior notice on a weekend, at which point she ended up with me. Then they sold the house 2 days later.

I want to know what my sister's rights were when she lived in the back part of the house for 30 plus years. Now she is with me in my trailer and they sold the house and would like to know what rights we have? No one put in any money except for us, which they said was rent from us living there.

Comment: I am the one who wrote this question and I forgot to mention I am one of the 10 owners that this house was left to. and their also was another house in florida and a corvette, garage kept, also involved with the sale.

Comment: Sorry to hear of your problems but the questions you are asking are mostly about legal matters and thus not appropriate for this site. I suspect they are not appropriate for law.SE either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mostly about legal issues and only peripherally about personal finance.

Comment: This is very unclear. Who are the "they" who charged you rent and who sold the house? Also, this sounds like a legal question rather than personal finance, and you will need to say where you are.

Comment: What is "fair" is irrelevant.  What the _will_ says is paramount.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.  Unfortunately, that isn't something you can really do here.

Comment: @DStanley The will and inheritance law, yes.

Answer (score 9):

Rent doesn't give you any ownership in a property, so is largely irrelevant here. If you were paying rent after the death of your parents, that money would go to the owners of the house (which may include you). Similarly, whether or not someone was evicted is completely irrelevant.

If the will specifies how the estate should be divided, that's what's relevant here. You seem to imply that the house was left to 10 people. Barring specific other arrangements, the most likely case is that the house will be sold by the executrices and the proceeds divided evenly between all ten people.

Again, though, it's going to depend on the specifics of the will. There are many possible cases where you may end up with nothing. For example, if there are a lot of debts, these must be paid off before dividing up the money from the sale of the house.

If you are not getting the answers you need from the executrices, you need to consult a lawyer.

Comment: God bless you sir for making sense of the question and providing a relevant answer.

Comment: And even if you *are* getting answers from them, you might want a lawyer anyway. Normally you'd want to avoid lawyers and family, but your sisters have already tossed you and your sister out on the street, I'd say any bridges have been sufficiently burned.

Answer (score 4):

If your sister paid rent, she was a tenant. There are laws to protect tenants, but those depend on what country, state, and city you live in. In most places in the US (maybe all), she was owed more than 2 days notice. Normally, the local housing authority could help her figure out what her rights are, but since this already happened, they may not be able to do much (depends on the local laws). It's worth asking them anyway. I don't know how partial ownership of the property would affect things if your sister was a partial owner.

If the 30 year old will was the most recent document, then that's how the estate will be distributed. There are no laws in the US requiring a will to be fair. An executor's role is to carry out the will. Being an executor does not mean one can choose to unilaterally sell the property in the estate without permission of other heirs. You'll need to speak with a lawyer if you think they're breaking the will by selling property that you have partial ownership of. But since the sale is already done, reversing it would be slow and probably very expensive in legal fees. If it's a small estate, you'll have to judge whether a lawyer is worth the money and the family's animosity. Also, if the estate had debt, debt must be paid before property is distributed to the heirs, so that could also change what your sisters had to do.

I'd suggest first asking your sisters to tell  you about what they've done to execute the will, and what they do in the future.

Comment: Thank you Karen, their has been financial situations with this as well. They sold our parents home for next to nothing. They also waited quite sometime before they listed it. Over a  yr. went by when they had money from the sale of my parents home and corvette, plus the money we were paying to live their. They were supposed to abide by the will, which states to invest or reinvest to make the most for the heirs, meaning me and 9 others, including them.  And they did not follow his wishes.  I don't know how other estates are handled but no letters, no correspondence and  selling it without us.

Comment: If the executors did not follow the will, then you'd have grounds for a law suit. Whether it would be worth the lawyer's fees depends on how much the estate is worth. If you think they cheated you out of a million dollars, it's very likely worth the trouble and expense of going to court. If you think they cheated you out of $100, the lawyer's bill would certainly be at least several thousand, it's just not worth fighting over.